# Can a wizard copy prepared spells into a spellbook?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard

My spellbook got destroyed by water, and the DM decided that was enough for my spellbook to stop working. This means that my Wizard will need a new spellbook, but I still have several spells prepared. I've found a new spellbook on a Wizard we encountered and I now have their spells. Does a prepared spell allow me to copy it back into a spellbook?

Kind of related: [What can a wizard do without a spellbook?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59419/what-can-a-wizard-do-without-a-spellbook)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, and this is explicitly stated on page 114 of the *Player's Handbook* in the "Your Spellbook" sidebar in the Wizard class description. It works exactly as you are hoping:

> If you lose your spellbook, you can use the [procedure in the preceeding paragraph] to transcribe the spells **that you have prepared** into a new spellbook. Filling out the  remainder of your spellbook requires you to find new spells to do so, as normal. For this 
>   reason, many wizards keep backup spellbooks in a safe place.

See the rest of the sidebar for costs and time required.

Comment: But can previously scribed spells be copied to the new spellbook?