# Does a wizard need to read their spellbook to ritual cast from it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, concentration

The wizard spellcasting rules say...

> You can cast a wizard spell as a ritual if that spell has the ritual tag and you have the spell in your spellbook. You don't need to have the spell prepared.

It makes *sense* that to cast the spell, which you didn't prepare today, you'd have to read it from your spellbook. Mostly this isn't an important distinction, but there is a notable exception: the spellshard item (Eberron: Rising from the Last Wwar p.279).

> While holding the shard, you can use an action to open your mind to the shard, seeing its content in your mind. On subsequent rounds, reading the text or scribing new text on blank "pages" in the shard requires concentration (as if concentrating on a spell) and takes the same amount of time it takes you to read and write normally. (...) A wizard can use a spellshard as a spellbook, with the usual cost in gold and time to "scribe" a spell into the shard.

Thus, reading the spellshard requires you to concentrate on it... as does ritual casting a spell, since it has a cast time longer than one action.

> Certain spells (including spells cast as rituals) require more time to cast: minutes or even hours. When you cast a spell with a casting time longer than a single action or reaction, you must spend your action each turn casting the spell, and you must maintain your concentration while you do so (see “Concentration” below). If your concentration is broken, the spell fails, but you don’t expend a spell slot. If you want to try casting the spell again, you must start over.

Given all of the above... is it impossible to ritual cast a spell stored in a spellshard?

Comment: I think that this question has been already asked in the linked post. If you think that yours has different aspects, you may include those to explain where the differences are.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to read a spell from your spellbook in order to ritual cast it.

You have already listed the requirements of ritual casting, and reading the spell from your spellbook is not one of them.

Comment: This answer is correct, but could be more supported, such as by citing the clarification in SAC.  Cf. Eddymage's [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/188278/23547) to [Can a Wizard cast a spell as a ritual without physically accessing a spellbook?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/132014/23547)